# spectrum of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading the  post [here](http://mathramble.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/the-spectrum-of-a-direct-sum-of-rings/). My question is :

In the part $1$ implies $3$, why is $r_1'$ is not equal to $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Do you mean the part i) $\implies$ iii)?

Comment: Yes, I was sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry we just need to show that $r_1' \neq 0$. But $\alpha$ is a unit and $r_1$ isn't nilpotent (there exist primes not containing it) so $r_1' := \alpha r_1$ isn't nilpotent.